# Beckhoff TwinCAT 3 integration with Matlab Simulink

Tags: matlab, simulink, twincat, twincat-ads

I have the following problem when trying to integrate a Simulink model in TwinCAT (through Visual Studio 2019): When Adding new item under "TcCOM Objects" I don't see the "TE1400 Module Vendor" where the Simulink model should be.

[Screenshot: Missing TE1400](https://i.stack.imgur.com/YiXnr.png)

[TE1400 present](https://i.stack.imgur.com/Y16mF.png)

This is my setup:

- Visual Studio 2017 and 2019 was installed with C++ and .NET Developer tools
- XAE and TE140x were installed after Visual Studio
- SetupTE14xx.p ran with the Simulink model in the same folder

Answer (score 0):

The binaries of your Simulink-Model-TcComObject have to be in this path C:\TwinCAT\3.1\CustomConfig\Modules on the engineering system. Otherwise the engineering will not find it. Please check what's really in there.
Maybe [beckhoff-infosys](https://infosys.beckhoff.com/content/1033/te1400_tc3_target_matlab/10825694987.html?id=5735634961503816348) also helps: